# Microcontroller shared ground with different power supplies

Tags: microcontroller, ground, teensy

I'm looking at a similar setup to the one shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o-GOX1PsB0&ab_channel=kaboomjones). What confuses me is that the Teensy microcontroller is receiving power from the USB connection, the servo motor is receiving power from the external 6v battery, but the microcontroller and servo motor are sharing the same ground line. Is there an isolated part of the Teensy that is being powered by the USB connection? I'm missing some fundamental understanding of how this setup works because I thought the input voltage is relative to the ground. In other words, is this OK to share a ground line between components regardless of what device is being used to power them? How does the USB input from the computer to the Teensy seamlessly share relative voltage with the isolated power supply?

I have a regulated power supply that I want to power a servo motor with while using the Teensy to handle the logic. Is it safe to share a ground line between the Teensy and power supply without causing issues to any of the involved devices? [Example image](https://ibb.co/jZKY5XQ) of what I'm wondering is correct. I have an external power supply which is the alligator clips in the left of the picture going in the +v column of the breadboard that is powering the servo motor, the ground of the external power supply connected to the Teensy ground and the servo motor ground, and one of the PWM pins of the Teensy sending the logic to the signal input for the servo motor.

Comment: Post a picture of your setup. But in general if you want two devices to be electrically connected they are going to share a ground or else something a lot more complicated (antenna, optical fiber, etc.)

Comment: @user1850479 https://ibb.co/jZKY5XQ is a picture I took of what I was planning on doing. I also edited the original post with a description if it isn't clear what's going on in the picture.

Comment: An electric circuit is a circle that current flows around. Your picture shows connecting the motor and microcontroller, so if you were planning on electrical signals moving through them you must complete the circuit by connecting the grounds. If you don't connect the grounds no circuit exists and the MCU will not be in communication with the motor.

Comment: The general case is that the different parts of your circuit *must* share a ground between them, whether or not they have separate power supplies. Every signal needs a 0V reference to measure against, so if you don't share the ground as this 0V reference you can't get signals between the different parts of the circuit.